# How can I send a HTML table in an email using PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress

I made a wordpress plugin that sends emails. I would like to send a table as message in the email. If I try to write every row one by one it works, but it is not  if I try this:

```
for ($i=01; $i < 25; $i++) {
$from = $i-1;
$to = $i ;
$message.= '<th scope="col">' . $from . ' - ' . $to . '</th>';
```

How can I make it work?
I would appreciate if someone guide me about that.

Comment: What _exactly_ doesn't work? What _is_ the result? You know you're missing a closing `}` above for your `for` loop, right?

Comment: Just as side note `01` is octal number, so in future if you write `011` it will not be decimal 11, but decimal 9

Comment: another sidenote. If you are using `.=` you need to have defined `$message` before you start looping. Otherwise, you'll get an error stating you cannot append to a non-existing variable.

Comment: Note that with a properly closed loop and an initialized `$message` variable, what you have above "works" just fine.  [See Here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/381471aabeb034dffec30c0b312457549aa27de5).  If you are expecting a different result, you need to be more specific.

Comment: So again, what exactly is the problem? What is the expected result and what is the actual result? In your comment directly above, "there email sent" makes is sounds like there is no problem.

Comment: Sorry. I wanted to say that the plugin does not send the email if I put the loop in it.

Answer (score 0):

You wanna make sure you are setting the `$message` variable before incrementing its value.

You cannot increment the value of a variable if it does not exist.

For example:

```
# Invalid
$i++; // NOTICE Undefined variable: i on line number 2

# Valid
$i = 0;
$i++;
```

The same goes for a string. So your code should look something like this:

```
<?php

# Set the $message variable
$message = "";

for( $i = 0; $i < 25; $i++ ) {
  $from = $i - 1;
  $to = $i;

  $message .= "<th scope=\"col\">$from - $to</th>"; # now increment it.

} # Make sure to close your for loop
```